# match numbers or numbers and comma

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to check if my string is numbers or numbers and comma, no other character is allowed.

That's my try:

```
if(myStr.match(/\d+(,\d+)*/g)) {
        console.log("valid");
} else {
        console.log("not valid"); 
}
```

It doesn't work as I wants, for example:

```
myStr = "12,15,as";
```

is "valid", but it shouldnt.

How can I fix it?

Comment: should 12,12,12 be valid? Or only one comma allowed?  Should 12, be valid?

Comment: Use `/^\d+(,\d+)*$/.test(myStr)`

Comment: yes, 12,12,12 is valid, Wiktor's comment works! thanks